# php proc_open different behavior in CLI and FPM

Tags: php, proc-open

I am using `proc_open` to parse some process results. But I get different behavior of `proc_open` when I call my script by different methods.

When I call it from bash, like `php test.php`, it's all ok; `proc_open` returns the expected process result, but if I call my script using php-fpm then I get something like process system calls log:

```
"SIGNAL received /usr/share/bin/prog-cli(print_backtrace+0x2f)[0x46ef2f].."
```

Where `prog-cli` is my process. I swapped the CLI and FPM `php.ini` config, but I got this problem again.

My proc_open code:

```
$descriptors = array(
                0 => array('pipe', 'r'),
                1 => array('pipe', 'w'),
                2 => array('pipe', 'w'),
            );
$procResource = proc_open( $process, $descriptors, $pipes, '/tmp', [], null);
```

Why am I seeing the correct result from CLI, but not FPM?

Answer (score 0):

Because I forget that the process is running in the name of user `www-data`, it hasn't the required permissions and I get the output of a system error in a strange form.